# how to split the variable input by users to an array

Tags: php

A variable $irn input by the users, I need to pass the variable $irn one by one to a SQL and display the result in GR textbox after clicking the button
Generate Result, I want to split the $irn to an array so I can pass it one by one to the SQL query.

I tried mb_split and preg_split

```html
<?php
include "big2gb.php";

ini_set('default_charset', 'utf-8');

$result = $_GET["listIRN"];
$irn = $_POST["irn"];

$serverName = "192.168.4.75";

$connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"SAFHKG", "UID"=>"sa1", "PWD"=>"Azsxdc11", "CharacterSet" => "UTF-8");
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo );

if($conn){
   //echo "connect DB success!!!<br />";
         }
   else
   {
             //echo "successfully failed!!!<br />";
             die(print_r(sqlsrv_errors(),true));
   }  
//find irn   
$sql="Select Top 1
[Expression] = CONCAT(OFFICIALNUMBER, ' for ', TITLE, ' in Class ', LOCALCLASSES)
From CASES
INNER JOIN OFFICIALNUMBERS On CASES.CASEID = OFFICIALNUMBERS.CASEID
Where NUMBERTYPE IN ('R', 'A') and CASES.IRN = ('".$array[$i]."')
Order By
CASE 
 When NumberType = 'R' then -2
 When Numbertype = 'A' then -1
End";

echo"
<table>
  <form action='test22.php' method='post'>  
 <tr>
    <td>IRN:</td>
    <td>
 <input type='text' id='txtIRN' value='' style='text-transform:uppercase' >
 
 <input type='button' value='Add IRN' onClick='addIRN()' name=''/>
 
 <input type='submit' value='Genarate Result' id='GR' name=''/>
 </td> 
 </tr>
 <tr><tr><tr> 
 <td><td>
 <textarea id='listIRN' name='irn' rows='40' cols='30' >
 
 </textarea><textarea id='GR' rows='40' cols='80' ></textarea>
 </td></td>
 </tr></tr></tr>  
  </form> 
</table><br/>";

echo"
<script type='text/javascript'>
function addIRN(irn) {
    var IRNText = document.getElementById(\"txtIRN\").value;
 var IRNList = document.getElementById(\"listIRN\").value;
 
 var irn = IRNList + '\\n' + IRNText;
 
 document.getElementById(\"listIRN\").value = irn.trim().toUpperCase();
}
</script>";
//////////////////your entered//////////////////*
   echo "<p>You entered:<p>";
  $array = mb_split('\\n', $irn);
   foreach($array as $line)
   {
   $array = explode('\s', $irn); 
      echo "$line\n";
   }  
//////////////////////////////////////////////


print_r ($array); 

//echo $array[3];
//echo $array[0];


for ($i = 0; $i <= 20; $i++) 
{     
$result = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql );

 while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $result, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOc) )
 {
  echo " ". $row["Expression"] ." <br />";
 }
}

$conn->close(); 

?>
```

strong text

User input will be like TM1150CN31 TM2846CN35 TM2855CN35 TM2865CN35 TM2874CN43 TM3367CN05

Comment: _“User input will be like […]”_ - are those supposed to be simple space characters between the values? You are trying to split by line breaks in your code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use explode function like below

```
$var = 'TM1150CN31 TM2846CN35 TM2855CN35 TM2865CN35 TM2874CN43 TM3367CN05';
$array = explode(' ', $var);
```

Out put will be like

```
Array
(
    [0] => TM1150CN31
    [1] => TM2846CN35
    [2] => TM2855CN35
    [3] => TM2865CN35
    [4] => TM2874CN43
    [5] => TM3367CN05
)
```